# Ошибка при парсинге: bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ip-adress.com/proxy-list'

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def soup(html):
    b = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

def main():
    url = 'https://www.ip-adress.com/proxy-list'
    soup(get_html(url))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Антон/PycharmProjects/doesntmatter/venv/dDos.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Антон/PycharmProjects/doesntmatter/venv/dDos.py", line 11, in main
    soup(get_html(url))
  File "C:/Users/Антон/PycharmProjects/doesntmatter/venv/dDos.py", line 8, in soup
    b=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
  File "C:\Users\Антон\PycharmProjects\doesntmatter\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 216, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Место возникновения проблемы тут:

```
b = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

Причина в том, что `lxml` является сторонним модулем и его нет среди установленных модулей.

Установить его можно так: `pip install lxml`

Либо используйте парсер, что будет "из коробки":

```
b = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: я устанавливал lxml

Comment: Попробуйте запустить код с `from lxml import html`, будет ошибка?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml' но я устанавливал.

Comment: >pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\py\lib\site-packages (4.4.2)

Comment: @m1dn1ght, я бы использовал `'html.parser'` он может медленнее парсить, но в комплекте. Но если вам нужен lxml, то убедитесь что интерпретатор, куда вы установили lxml и тот, что используется при запуске один и тот же. Например, в переменных средах PATH будет путь к папке питона и если вы в консоли запускали команду, то в тот питон и поставится. Кроме того, у вас могут стоять переменные среды, например, при создании проекта IDE по умолчанию создаст, тогда это будет другая папка питона

Comment: Ладно,спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @m1dn1ght, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)